# cannon.js Fire bullets， The bullet passed through the object without collision

Tags: cannon.js

I use cannon.js to simulate firing bullets. The bullet passed through the object without collision. I know this is because the speed is too fast. The bullet passes through the object at the interval of two frames. Is there any way to avoid this situation

Comment: having the same problem. maybe there is no solution, apart from hacking around with raycast/hitscan